# how to get elements in grid-view from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I trying to use date-picker bootstrap on text-box inside gridview.  I am not able to figure out how to get access the text-box inside the gridview.  i am getting error: txtStartDate does not exist.

```
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dp = $('#<%=txtStartDate.ClientID%>');
            dp.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
                language: "tr"
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });
        });
</script>
```

and here is my text box

```
  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Start Date">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Start_Date")%>'
                                  BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>                            
                        <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: getting error where? jQuery won't throw that error

Comment: certainly assumed so @mason. Was sort of pointing out it's important to be more specific about errors

Answer (score 0):

Apply a CSS class to your text box, then use a CSS class selector to select all elements with that class to apply the datepicker to.

```
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dp = $('.dp');
            dp.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
                language: "tr"
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });
        });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Start_Date")%>' BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" CssClass="dp"></asp:TextBox>
```

The reason you were getting the exception was because there is no `txtStartDate` in the scope where that code executes. Each data row will have a `txtStartDate` control, but you can't refer to them outside the context of a GridView row.